# AJAX code for calling code-behind method from aspx page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Upon click of an anchor link, I want to call a code-behind function (which loads some HTML content code into the page).

The code-behind:

```
public void loadNewPage(string id)
    {
        ltlContent.Text = getPageCenter(id);
    }
```

The JS code:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = { userName: $(this).attr("id") };
            var dataVal = JSON.stringify(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/loadNewPage()",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: dataVal,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (id) {
                }
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="kontakt">Go to Kontakt</a>
```

What I get is only that `#` is being added at the back of the URL and the code-behind function is not called.

Comment: your `dataVal`consist of `{'username':idvalue}` and your method expects an argument id, besides, remove () from  `url:"Default.aspx/loadNewPage()"`

Comment: wrap your key also in quotes in data i.e. var data ={'id':value}

Comment: I think your code-behind may be wrong. You cannot access controls on the page from a web service call. i.e. `ltlContent` will be inaccessible

Comment: @zgood - so what do you suggest about injecting the HTML code, from string, into the page ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in your anchor do this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="kontakt">Go to Kontakt</a>
```

and modify your ajax script to this:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {

     var data = { 'id': $(this).attr("id") };
     var dataVal = JSON.stringify(data);

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/loadNewPage",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dataVal,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (id) {
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: I have tried the `href="javascript:void(0)"` way before and it didn't work. Ofc, I don't get the `#` added, but the function still doesn't get called. 
And even when I fixed `username` to `id`, still no effect.

Comment: try debugging your script, use chrome debugger(f12) or firebug, see what error is there

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null` is what I get. What I read about this is when the script is in the head, it gets loaded before the elements and then they're unaccessible. What do you suggest ?

Comment: see, that error simply means, whatever tag you're trying to find, is not available, either tag name is wrong or dom is not constructed yet. Try wrapping your entire js script in `$(document).ready(function(){ //here your code});` or place your entire code at the end of the `body`

Comment: Still unsuccessful. (did both things).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var data = { 'id': $(this).attr("id") };
         var dataVal = JSON.stringify(data);

         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/loadNewPage",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: dataVal,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var htmlStr = data.d;
                    $('#ltlContent').html(htmlStr);
                }
         });
    });
});
```

C# code-behind:

```
using System.Web.Services;

[WebMethod()]
public static string loadNewPage(string id) {
       string result = getPageCenter(id);
       return result;
}
```

If that all works then simply inject the html string wherever you want in the success of the jquery ajax call

Comment: Is it possible to make the code-behind method non-static ? Is it gonna work that way? 
And what do you mean by "putting the html string wherever I want in the success of ajax call" ? Isn't the `alert(data.d)` for that ?

Comment: As far as non-static methods, short answer: No. Long answer: [Read this](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/). On the return of the WebMethod call a json string is sent back and jQuery will automatically parse it to an object- `data` in this case. You can `console.log(data)` to see what it contains. The `data.d` is the payload from your `getPageCenter(id)` which I am assuming is an html string of the page you are trying to load (I could be wrong here). So you'll want to load that into your `ltlContent` control like so- `$('#ltlContent').html(data.d);`

Comment: Also, if your `ltlContent` control is a `<asp:Literal />` control you may have to change it to something like a `<asp:PlaceHolder />` because literal controls don't render html you can inject to, but placeholder controls render divs which you can inject html into. [Referance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz4949ks(v=vs.100).aspx)